# Condenser, (heat pump) covered in pollen - does it need to be vacuumed - pic attached

Tags: heat-pump

So my Condenser, (heat pump) is covered in pollen - does it need to be vacuumed or will the wind/rain take this away naturally?

Here is what it looks like:

[image]

Comment: I would assume it's designed for this environment and that rain will clean it well enough... but careful vacuuming probably wouldn't hurt. Whether you'd improve efficiency enough to offset the couple of cents of electricity used to run the vacuum, I have no idea.

Comment: Can probably save that and more by adding the missing insulation on the lowest line, mid left of picture. I'd assume hosing should be fine for this part that sits out in the weather, and might be more effective at removing the pollen inside the grid, though best to contact the maker if it's not mentioned in the manual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should clean it. Or better, have a professional clean it. Watch how they do it, and take notes.  Then next time, you can clean it yourself. The technician may take the cover off the unit, and spray from the inside out.

If you're going to do it yourself, check the manufacturer's documentation for the approved cleaning method.  It usually involves gently rinsing it with a garden hose, though may recommend a cleaning spray. There are loads of videos on YouTube, that describe how to properly clean the unit.

Whatever you do, be gentle, and DO NOT scrub, brush, or in any way touch the fins.  They are very delicate, and can be bent and damaged with the lightest touch. Even spraying them with a high pressure nozzle on your hose can cause damage, so be careful when cleaning the unit.

***Warning:*** Don't forget to turn the power off using the disconnect, before performing this, or any other maintenance on the unit.